# How to sketch the following discrete time signal $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \delta[n-k]$?

Tags: discrete-signals, homework

I tried to solve it like in the picture but It feels so wrong though.
[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question? Surely if you just want to sketch the signal, you just sketch $\delta[n] + \delta[n-1] +  \delta[n-2] +  \delta[n-3] + \ldots$ without invoking anything else?

Comment: @PeterK. How can you be so sure that the upper sum limit will be a positive integer? It might be -4 for example.

Comment: Good point! Are negatives allowed? Usually the summation goes up from the lower limit. My solution would work, but you’d have to take account of the direction of the summation (up for positive $n$ and down for negative).

Comment: More thought required! I’ll try to give a full answer after lunch.

Comment: Well usually in Signals and Systems the “n” denotes the discrete time meaning that n could be any integer value. I would like to hear your thoughts. Bon appetit :)

Comment: The answer to this question depends entirely on the meaning associated with a sum in which the lower limit exceeds the upper limit. One standard interpretation is that the sum is empty (and has value $0$) if the lower limit is larger that the upper limit. With this convention, $\sum_{k=0}^n  f[n]$ has value $0$ for any $f$ if $n < 0$ and so that sum is just $u[n]$. Another interpretation is analogous to what we use in _integrals,_ $$\int_a^b = -\int_b^a$$ making the sum be $u[n]$ for $n > 0$ and $-u[-n]$ for $n<0$ with a nice ambiguity for the value at $n=0$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yes, that makes sense.  My answer is assuming no sign change, as stated by the OP. Let's see what they come back with.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Assuming that the upper limit is negative we do a swap of variable such as m = -k and then the limits are swapped which is not a problem, or is it? I'm a little skeptical about what I just elaborated though. Would like to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Since the question is homework, try asking your instructor (or the instructor's deputy such as a teaching assistant) what the interpretation is. What CS people think can be determined by trying a short program such as `sum:=0; for k := 0 step 1 until n sum:= sum+delta[n-k]` where `n` is initialized to a negative value.  Is the `for` loop executed once? not executed at all? What if we used a `while` loop instead? What if, as good DSPissers, we used MATLAB or Octave and Python to do our thinking for us?

Answer (score 2):

Your signal is:
$$
x[n]  = \sum_{k=0}^n \delta[n - k]
$$
and you're saying you want to sketch it.

Based on your comment, I'm going to assume that 
$$x[-1] = \left . x[n] \right  |_{n=-1} =  \left . (\delta[n] + \delta[n+1]) \right  |_{n=-1} = 0 + 1 = 1$$
and that
$$x[+1] = \left . x[n] \right  |_{n=+1} =  \left . \left(\delta[n] + \delta[n-1]\right) \right  |_{n=+1} = 0 + 1 = 1$$

I believe that means
$$
x[n] = 1, ~~ \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
because
$$
x[n]   = \cdots + \delta[n - (n-2)] + \delta[n - (n-1)] + \delta[n - n] + \cdots
$$
if summing up or
$$
x[n]   = \cdots + \delta[n - (n+2)] + \delta[n - (n+1)] + \delta[n - n] + \cdots
$$
if summing down.

It's a little odd having the upper limit of the summation depend on the current time and, as I said in the comment, having the summation go down to the upper limit if the upper limit is below the lower one.

Comment: So this means that the signal is equal to 1 and it would be sketched as u[n]+u[-n-1]. As for the sum depending on the n, i don’t think it’s unsual, we get it all the time, especially when applying convolution. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @user3140379 Yes, but I think $x[n] = 1$ is simpler than $x[n] = u[n] + u[-n-1]$. YMMV

Comment: Yeah but the former helps more in terms of sketching :)

Comment: @user3140379 Hence "YMMV" (Your Mileage May Vary). :-)

Comment: I didn’t get that the first time :) Cheers!